# browser crashes while displaying 6000 Records in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display the large set of records  with ng-repeat, but the browser crashes.How could I display large dataset without using infinite scroll.

Comment: try to paginate the result

Comment: there is no reason to show `6000` records at a time as user is not going to view `6000` record at time, I'd say that either do pagination or use `infinite scroll`..

Comment: Agree with comments here that displaying 6000 things at once is likely not going to be a good user experience for anyone, so you should strongly think about paginating the results.

Comment: Agree with ur comments. But i have different table structure in a single Page and single scope variable binded all table's Value.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others suggest, 6000 rows begs to be paged, but technically angular can handle that. I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tonypatton/pen/EyEKXG) with angular generating 10k rows are using ng-repeat to display a table, to show its technically possible. I suggest you use `track-by` in your `ng-repeat` as well as `ng-cloak` to optimize the rendering of that much data.

```
   <tbody ng-cloak>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by item.key">
```

The reason your browser is crashing is likely due to the way the data is being created (possibly adding each row to the cope at a time and causing many render cycles), or due to the complexity of each rows display. So optimizations could allow you to display that much data without the browser crashing, but its still not a good idea (or a good user experience).

Answer (score 0):

6000 records is a problem that begs for paging in some form. Loading 6000 records in one go is not a good solution and especially not considering you are using Angular. You should use an Angular construct such as a dataTable which supports paging.

http://ng-table.com/#/